# Meaning of "get in one's face"

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain me the meaning of "get in your face"? There is this guy (an amateur musical actor) talking about his acting style. He says that his acting style is in the moment and that he can "come a little bit in your face... kind of". Can someone paraphrase what he means here, please?

Comment: His acting style can appear 'in-your-face', which is defined [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in-your-face).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever encountered an obnoxious guy who approached you so close that his face was about 4 inches from yours, then spoke loudly or shouted?  This is "getting in your face".

Occasionally this behavior is just because the individual is excessively "outgoing", or because he's trying to sell you something, but more commonly the intent is to intimidate.  This is the behavior of many high school bullies, eg.

[Several definitions](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+in+your+face)